# Changing input value on keyup (2 inputs)

Tags: jquery, keyup

This ist the html-code:

```
<form>
<label for="item1">Number 1</label>
<input type="text" id="item1">

<label for="item2">Number 2</label>
<input type="text" id="item2">
</form>

<form>
<input type="text" id="result1" disabled>
<input type="text" id="result2" disabled>
</form>
```

And the jquery:

```
// calculate: item1 x 50 = write to id "item2"
$('#item1').keyup(function () {
    var foo = parseFloat($(this).val());
    foo = Math.round(foo * 50);
    $('#item2').val(foo);
});

// calculate: item2 / 50 = write to id "item1"
$('#item2').keyup(function () {
    var foo = parseFloat($(this).val());
    foo = Math.round(foo / 50);
    $('#item1').val(foo);
});

// calculate: item1 * 13.99 = write to id "result1"
$('#item1').keyup(function () {
    var foo = parseFloat($(this).val());
    foo = Math.round(foo * 13.99);
    $('#result1').val(foo);
});
// calculate: item1 * 15.99 = write to id "result2"
$('#item1').keyup(function () {
    var foo = parseFloat($(this).val());
    foo = Math.round(foo * 15.99);
    $('#result2').val(foo);
});

// calculate: item1 * 18.99 = write to id "result3"
// calculate: item1 * 25.99 = write to id "result4"
// ....
```

Example on [jsfiddle.net/ra7d4f59/](http://jsfiddle.net/ra7d4f59/)

The input id´s item1 and item2 calculate against each other (*50 or /50).
I get the results only by typing a number in to input "item1". how can i also update the results by typing a number in to "item2" by using "item1"?

Comment: You have a typo on your last selector. It should be: `$('#item2')`

Comment: Anyway, you could merge these 4 handlers into just two, one for each `input`, or even better, to a single one.

Comment: the last selector is right. it should be #item1 because i only can calculate with number from #item1. item1*13.99, item1*15.99, ...

Comment: I got what's the issue. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't looking for changes on #item2 as of now, that's why it's not updating the result inputs. Since you have a lot of inputs to update, I'd suggest splitting this out to a function.

```
function updateResults() {
    var input1 = parseFloat($('#item1').val());
    foo = Math.round(input1 * 13.99);
    $('#result1').val(foo);
    // Similarly, 
    // calculate: item1 * 15.99 = write to id "result2"
    // calculate: item1 * 18.99 = write to id "result3"
    // calculate: item1 * 25.99 = write to id "result4"
}
// calculate: item1 x 50 = write to id "item2"
$('#item1').keyup(function () {
    var foo = parseFloat($(this).val());
    foo = Math.round(foo * 50);
    $('#item2').val(foo);
    updateResults();
});

// calculate: item2 / 50 = write to id "item1"
$('#item2').keyup(function () {
    var foo = parseFloat($(this).val());
    foo = Math.round(foo / 50);
    $('#item1').val(foo);
    updateResults();     
});
```

Hope this helps!

JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/d7vL2xyv/

Comment: @decibel - No problems, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally got what you're trying to do.

So basically, you can reduce your code to a `function` to calculate the results, and another one to handle the `keyup` `event` on both `inputs`:

```
$(function () {
    function calculate() {
        var el = $(this);
        var el1 = $('#item1');
        var el2 = $('#item2');
        var val1 = parseFloat(el1.val());
        var val2 = parseFloat(el2.val());

        if (el.attr('id') == el1.attr('id')) {
            val2 = Math.round(val1 * 50);
            el2.val(val2);
        }
        else {
            val1 = Math.round(val2 / 50);
            el1.val(val1);
        }

        $('#result1').val(Math.round(val1 * 13.99));
        $('#result2').val(Math.round(val1 * 15.99));
    }

    $('#item1, #item2').on('keyup', calculate);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/758z7uzf/1/)

Comment: If any answer solved your problem you need to mark it as the solution.